# What is the maximum deceleration for a car when it brakes and turns at the same time?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Given a maximum deceleration of a car when braking in a straight line, what is the maximum deceleration of a car when it brakes and turns at the same time? I was thinking that maybe it had something to do with the angle of tilt of the tires changing the direction of the braking force, but I am not 100% sure, maybe something can be done with vectors to achieve this?

Comment: Assuming the engine has more power than the breaks, just do a 180.

Comment: I'm quite confused, what do you mean by that?